# PostgreSQL - when is pg_advisory_xact_lock released, and when will persisted data be visible to other transactions

Tags: postgresql, locking

I am currently running PostgreSQL 13, but have also observed this behavior in PostgreSQL 11.  I am running into an issue where a UniqueConstraint violation error is thrown, but I would expect `pg_advisory_xact_lock` to be blocking until the transaction is committed (and visible to other transactions waiting on the lock) or rolled back.

I am calculating a unique `sort_id` for rows in a table based on a foreign key in the table within a web application. `UniqueConstraint(sort_id, foreign_key_value)`. We are utilizing `pg_advisory_xact_lock` in Python via SQL Alchemy and psycopg2.  Originally this was calculated based on a SQL Alchemy model (see most recent sort_id in the model's property).  I have also tried a direct query like (`SELECT max(sort_id) from table where foreign_key_value=:value;`) and still have run into constraint errors.

As concurrency of this API call / functionality increases, the rate of constraint errors increases.  Running single threaded, we never run into the constraint error.  This leads me to believe the lock may be released before the data is visible to other transactions.

When is `pg_advisory_xact_lock` released?  Will the data be visible to other transactions before the lock is taken by a different process?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the code. An advisory lock only blocks sessions who use it. A transaction that forgets to take the advisory lock is free to mess with the data. If possible, try locking the actual data, then that cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is `pg_advisory_xact_lock` released?

It's [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS):

> they are held until the current transaction ends; there is no provision for manual release

> Will the data be visible to other transactions before the lock is taken by a different process?

Not necessarily. For example, under the "repeatable read" isolation level, "the other" transaction sees data as of *its* start time, so if "the first" transaction commits after "the other" starts, the latter may not see the results of "the first".